# How to pre-fetch Debian packages on local network?

Tags: debian, package-management

Let's say I have at home 3 computers running Debian testing. They mostly have the same configuration and most of the packages installed are identical.

Every time I update/upgrade the Debian packages, they are downloaded from the Internet.

Is there a way to pre-fetch the Debian packages from the Internet and have a local, up-to-date Debian repository containing *only* the packages I have installed that have an available update?

So, typically, if I have vim installed and an update is released, my server will go and fetch the .deb locally and I could upgrade all my machines from the LAN. If I want to install emacs, then the local repository will not have it and it will be downloaded from the Internet.

One could call it a local apt caching system, like Squid does http caching.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are look for `apt-cacher`. To install it, just type:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-cacher
```

You can then configure `apt-get` to use it as proxy by creating a file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy` with content:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://cacher_ip:3142/";
```

To be honest, I am using this configuration on ubuntu, but it should be similar on debian. This way all package downloads will be requested from `apt-cacher` on server "cacher_ip". If it exists, it will be fetched locally. Otherwise, it will be downloaded via the cacher.

Comment: `apt-cacher-ng` is a good alternative, as well.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! The `apt-cacher` keyword helped me to find other alternatives, such as [approx](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/approx) and [apt-cacher-NG](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/).

Comment: @ShaneMadden: You are right. Actually, I am using `apt-cacher-ng`!

Comment: I have a strong preference for approx, mostly because the etch version of apt-cacher was kinda buggy for me.

Comment: etch is an old old old debian version. Things surely have changed :)

Comment: Just installed apt-cacher-ng today and it was remarkably easy. Recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The squid proxy actually does quite a good job "out of the box" caching apt-get downloads as well as a lot more besides that. With a few tweaks it will do an even better job.

See: http://itkia.com/using-squid-to-cache-apt-updates-for-debian-and-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Apt-cacher-ng cannot know exactly what's available as update for each user because the client's can uninstall the packages without telling the server (obviously) or sometimes the packages are renamed or splited up into multiple packages. There are just too many factors. If you can ignore most of them and want to pre-cache every package selecting them by names (of previously download packages), have a look at https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/html/howtos.html#mirroring